# Cast error when trying to implement Fody add-in

Tags: c#, mono, fody, compile-time-weaving

I'm trying to learn how to write a Fody module, and was following the [Pluralsight Fody course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/automatic-dotnet-code-weaving-fody/table-of-contents), which includes a walkthrough.

The sample add-in was to add an interface to any classes whose names ended in "DTO". He used the basic add-in from the Fody source, and changed the Execute() method as follows...

```
public void Execute() {
  typeSystem = ModuleDefinition.TypeSystem;
  TypeDefinition ifDef = new TypeDefinition("MarkerInterfaces", "DtoMarkerInterface", TypeAttributes.Interface | TypeAttributes.Public);
  ModuleDefinition.Types.Add(ifDef);
  IEnumerable<TypeDefinition> dtos = ModuleDefinition.GetTypes().Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("DTO"));
  foreach (TypeDefinition dto in dtos) {
    dto.Interfaces.Add(ifDef);
  }
}
```

However, when I do this, I get a compiler error on the last code line...

*Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition' to 'Mono.Cecil.InterfaceImplementation'*

Anyone any idea what the problem is? I'm not experienced enough in this stuff to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
dto.Interfaces.Add(new InterfaceImplementation(ifDef));
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it :)

Comment: Sorry, was going to, but then found it's not working as I expected. I just haven't had time to look at it yet. Don't worry, you'll get the points :)

Comment: Turns out that the code was working, it was the test that wasn't! Thanks again for the help